# Linux Mint 18 can't connect to PEAP-MSCHAPv2 encrypted school wifi

Tags: networking, linux-mint, wifi, networkmanager

Freshly installed Linux mint 18, Cinnamon desktop. My computer is Dell Vostro 5460, and the wireless card is intel wireless-N 2230.

I can connect to WPA/WPA2 home wifi and the wireless network without password in my university without problem, but I can't connect to my university`s PEAP-MSCHAPv2 encrypted wireless network. After I click the "connect" button, it just keeps spinning, and does not prompt a window for user name and password.

I have previously installed Ubuntu 16.04.1 on this machine, and it can connect all the wifi smoothly. Hope to get some solutions.

Comment: Fill a bugreport: https://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/+bugs

Comment: Have you resolved this issue ? Same problem on 18.1

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. You need to connect via "Connect to Hidden Network..."

1. From the system tray open "Connect to Hidden Network..."
2. In the first dialog insert the network name you are trying to connect.
3. Choose you security level.
4. Hit connect.
5. Now modify the network settings.
6. Done.